# Fast/Quick way to farm Demon Eyes/ Wandering Eyes?

Tags: terraria, terraria-mobile

So, I beat all the mech bosses, I had a would where I stored a black lens, but deleted it... and, the black lenses have a 1% drop rate, but every night, about 3 demon eyes spawn, and about 2 wandering eyes, and I have been killing them repeatedly for about 5 hours, but still no black lens. Is there a way to get more to spawn/ farm them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do believe there are two items that allow for increased spawn:

- **Water Candle**, found on shelves and tables in Dungeons.
- **Battle Potion**, which can be found in chests and pots.

And I'm sure you know this already, but **Blood Moon** events increase monster spawn rates (for eyes that is) as well, and they have a 1/9 chance every non-New Moon night, so make sure to be on the surface when they occur.

I apologize for any mistakes in my answer, as I haven't played since just before 1.2

Source: [Terraria Wiki Spawn page](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Spawn#Affects_Monster_Spawn_Rate)

Comment: Well, luckly, mobile terraria (what I play on) is 1.2! Thank you for helping me.